# Prepopulating Survey123 form field inputs from related tables in file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, arcgis-collector, arcgis-survey123

I have a Survey123 survey. I am trying to prepopulate fields for from ArcGIS Collector and am having great difficulty.

To explain, I created a file geodatabase in ArcGIS 10.X, (relationship classes based on GlobalIDs), and published it as a feature service to ArcGIS Online (AGOL). This geodatabase has a point feature class and five related tables. I created a Survey123 from the feature service that submits results back into one of the related tables.

In the web map I created for Collector, I configured the popup to link the Survey123 survey to the Collector app (so that when the user has the map open in the Collector app, all they do is click the link and it sends them automatically to the Survey123). My goal is, that when the user selects a point on the map and follows the popup link to the survey123 form, that some of the survey123 field inputs are already populated from the same fields in the related tables from the file geodatabase.

I followed this article a lot for my overall process:
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000021198

This is an example of what my popup link in the web map looks like:

```
arcgis-survey123://?itemID=c5exampleitemid243284232599&field:ParentGUID={GUID}&field:NAME={relationships/0/NAME}
```

I saw on this article, that someone used the backward-slash `\` symbol instead of the forward-slash `/` mark in the attribute names, so it would look like `&field:NAME={relationships\0\NAME}` instead:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/populating-survey123-answers-with-related-tables/m-p/797787

That didn't work for me either, though.

I haven't been able to find much other documentation on this one particular problem. Not sure if it just doesn't work on my apps on my particular device (Android Galaxy phone), or if there's something wrong with my URL link in my web map popup, or maybe something else altogether.

Comment: Could not figure out, and is possible that pulling data from related tables into collector popups and passing it to survey123 just isn't available yet. Here are some resources I found with the those conclusions:

Comment: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-collector-questions/popups-not-displaying-correctly-in-collector/m-p/473115 and https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-collector-questions/are-the-arcade-featureset-functions-supported-in-collector/td-p/189300/page/3   .

Comment: To go around this dilemma, I joined my feature class to my tables, overwrote my feature service, and just pulled field inputs from the newly-created feature class: `&field:fieldname={fieldname}`